# Difficulty printing filenames with ObjC

Tags: objective-c, xcode, printf, nsfilemanager

I'm having some trouble printing a list of file names retrieved with NSFileManager. The documentation says it returns an array of strings - but my output is blank. In the code sample below, execution reveals the index with colon and nothing else... I am a long time java programmer but total newb to c/objc. Am I just misusing printf? Thanks for your help!

> Output: 
>   About to print file list ----------------------- 
>   Number of files: 29
>   0: 
>   1: 
>   2: 
>   3: 
>   4: 
>   5: 
>   6: 
>   7: 
>   8: 
>   9: 
>   10: 
>   11: 
>   12: 
>   13: 
>   14: 
>   15: 
>   16: 
>   17: 
>   18: 
>   19: 
>   20: 
>   21: 
>   22: 
>   23: 
>   24: 
>   25: 
>   26: 
>   27: 
>   28:

```
- (IBAction)printFileList:(id)sender{
NSFileManager *fm = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
NSString *path = @"/";
NSArray *files = [fm contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:NULL];
printf("About to print file list ----------------------- \n");
int fileCount = [files count];
printf("Number of files: %d", fileCount);
for(int i = 0; i<fileCount; i++){
    printf("%d: %s\n", i, [files objectAtIndex:i]);
}
```

}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't use `%s` as a format specifier for `NSString *`, since `NSString *` is a pointer, not a C string. Change your `printf` line to:

```
printf("%d: %s\n", i, [[files objectAtIndex:i] UTF8String]);
```

Comment: Could the line also be changed from "%d: %s\n" to "%d: %@\n" ?